# PHP GET Variable

Tags: php

As I'm a total noob I would like to excuse myself in advance for asking something obvious. I'm working on a HTML web front that would take over some variables from the form to a preformated text file on the other side. I was trying to setup a primary form where the data would be input:

```
<form action="input.php" method="GET">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

    <input type="submit" value="Add to text">
  </form>
```

My input.php is setup in such a way that the name value should nestle inside preformated text. All this is placed inside a fopen function. Something like "This is $name and he is doing great!". Here is the input.php:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "This is ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$name = echo ($_GET['name']);
fwrite($myfile, $name);
$txt = " and he is doing great!";
fwrite ($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

After I press the submit button on the first form page I get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)" for the eight row. This is the row with the echo. I did try to use POST instead of GET and the result is still the same.

Is what I want even possible/doable?

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't, use echo there. Just remove it.

Comment: replace $name = echo ($_GET['name']); with echo $name = $_GET['name'];

Comment: ^ no, just `$name = $_GET['name'];` or just use the get variable, no need to create a new variable

Comment: Oh Oh @sumit. That is incorrect

Comment: Tnx guys - Works now! Just amazed how fast things are solved here.